# Apply $elemMatch to multiple arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The result of my query is:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5e680bca55f2885cb3c864"), 
    "barcelona" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "david", 
            "age" : 17.0
        }
    ]
}
```

My query looks like this:

```
    db.test8.find({ line: '2' },{ barcelona: { $elemMatch: {
    date : 
    {
        "$gte" : ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00Z"), 
        "$lt" : ISODate("2018-07-02T00:00:00Z") 
    }
    }}});
```

The dataset looks like this in the mongodb. It has three arrays: barcelona, paris, and london. I will answer any questions you may have.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b5e680bca55f2885cb3c864"), 
    "piwikID" : "2", 
    "barcelona" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "david", 
            "age" : 11.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "damo", 
            "age" : 16.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "dani", 
            "age" : 12.0
        }
    ], 
    "paris" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "david", 
            "age" : 17.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "damo", 
            "age" : 10.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "danp", 
            "age" : 13.0
        }
    ], 
    "london" : [
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "dan", 
            "age" : 11.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-02T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "donner", 
            "age" : 12.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-07-03T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
            "name" : "dangus", 
            "age" : 14.0
        }
    ]
};
```

There are other cities `paris`, `london`, etc. which are arrays and should display in my result. 
How can I modify my query to show them in my result as well?

Comment: can you show your collection where you run this query

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I added the dataset to my post.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for multiple arrays first, you need to build the dynamic query.

Suppose you know the city names before you queried the DB you can build a query like this.

```
var cities = ['barcelona', 'paris', 'london'];
var query = {
    "$or": []
};
for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    let queryObj = {};
    queryObj[cities[i]] = {
        "$elemMatch": {
            date:
            {
                "$gte": ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00Z"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2018-07-02T00:00:00Z")
            }
        }
    };
    query["$or"].push(queryObj);
};
```

Your query like this :

> ```
> {
>     "$or":
>     [{ "barcelona": { "$elemMatch": { "date": { "$gte": ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00Z"), "$lt": ISODate("2018-07-02T00:00:00Z") } } } },
>     { "paris": { "$elemMatch": { "date": { "$gte": ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00Z"), "$lt": ISODate("2018-07-02T00:00:00Z") } } } },
>     { "london": { "$elemMatch": { "date": { "$gte": ISODate("2018-07-01T00:00:00Z"), "$lt": ISODate("2018-07-02T00:00:00Z") } } } }]
> }
> ```

```
db.col.find(query);
```